# Error writing R Dataframe in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, r, dataframe

I am writing a dataframe in R to Microsoft SQL server table and seeing below error. I have required permissions to insert records to this table, `dbo.temp2` but it is failing with this error. The number of columns in Dataframe and Table are matching.

```
dbWriteTable2(connDBI,"dbo.temp2",test.df1,append=TRUE,overwrite=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,add.id=TRUE)
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT id FROM dbo.temp2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'
```

Also tried with function `dbWriteTable` from DBI package and it is failing with Create table error even though am using `append=TRUE` option.

Answer (score 0):

I could able to resolve this issue with some online research and use of RMySQL package.

Below is the line of R code which fixed this and now am able to write the Dataframe into SQL Database table.

```
RMySQL::dbWriteTable(connDBI,name = "temp2" 
,value=test.df1,append=TRUE,row.names=FALSE,overwrite=FALSE)
```